# JQPlot pie chart from json

Tags: php, json, jqplot

I've the following code below to render a jqplot pie chart. 
For some reasons, the pie chart did not display the percentage properly.

```
$array= array(array("Males", $males),array("Female", $females));
json_encode($array);
```

The output of the json file is:

```
[["Books","8"],["Female","0"]]
```

But the display for the pie chart is showing 10% instead of 100, this is my renderer for pie chart

```
$.getJSON('jqPlot.php', function (data) {

        var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', [data], {
            seriesDefaults: {
                // Make this a pie chart.
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                    // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                    showDataLabels: true
                },
            },
            legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }});
    });
});
```

But if I change the json file to `[["Books","8"]]` the pie chart is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try this,working fine.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var items1 = new Array();
    var j=0;
    for ( var i in data ) {
        var items = new Array();
        items.push(i,Number(data[i]));
        items1[j++] = items;
    }

    var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', eval([items1]), {

                seriesDefaults:{
                    renderer:jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                    rendererOptions:{
                        dataLabels:'value',
                        showDataLabels:true
                    }
                },
                legend:{ show:true, location:'e' }
            }
    );

});
```